# Splitting a MySQL result array to output a sum and category title

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, phpexcel

I have an inventory table in my MySQL database as part of an application that I use to track items that my company has stored.

I'm currently working on the billing end of the application, in which I'm allowing for an Excel report to be exported via PHPExcel. The items in the 'items' table have a company id and category id. The categories are a children of the companies for organization.

For my Excel export, I'll only be working with one company at a time, so I my SQL query joins my items table to my categories table, so I have names to work with.

I have all of this working great, but I'm trying to keep a running total of the monthly fees per category and keep a title to each section. As such, I want the exported database data split into chunks by category.

My current SQL statement in my Codeigniter model:

```
    function get_inventory_fees($where = array())
    {
        // Function that returns object of items table with area calculation and charge calculations grouped by items
        $this->db->select('i.bbn bbn, i.name item_name, c.name cat_name, i.date_recd date_received, SUM(i.length * i.width * i.height * i.qty) area, i.location location, r.rate, SUM(i.length * i.width * i.height * i.qty * r.rate) fee');
        $this->db->join('rates r', 'r.name = i.location');
        $this->db->join('categories c', 'c.id = i.cat');
        $this->db->where('shipped IS NULL', null, false);
        $this->db->group_by('i.id');
        $this->db->order_by('cat_name asc, location asc');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('items i', $where);
        return $query;
    }
```

My loop code:

```
    $category_total = 0;
    $category_name = '';
    foreach($this->inventory->result() as $data)
    {
        if($data->cat_name != $category_name)
        {               
            if($category_total > 0)
            {
                $row++;
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(6, $row, 'Total:');
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(7, $row, $category_total);
                $row++;
                $category_total=0;
            }
            $row++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $row, $data->cat_name);
            $category_name = $data->cat_name;
            $row++;
        }
        $col = 0;
        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $data->$field);
            $col++;
        }
        $category_total+=$data->fee;

        $row++;
    }
```

I'm trying to avoid nesting queries as that is what I did in my previous version of my application. It would get dreadfully slow, but it did work. This time around, I'm redesigning things with Codeigniter and hopefully a little bit more experience.

My problem with my current code, however, is that I get no total on my last category as there is no next category to compare it to. Unfortunately, I don't have enough caffeine to figure it out from here. Any ideas or better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I havent worked with code igniter so i'll just point out a possible solution i use in some cases but you'll have to find a way to integrate it.

You could maybe use WITH ROLLUP in your group by. WITH ROLLUP adds NULL LINES and a sum for each group by, so you might be interrested by this solution but i'm not totally sure.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/group-by-modifiers.html

```
Example|data
------------
1      |1
2      |1
3      |2
4      |2
5      |2

SELECT SUM(example) as sum_example, data FROM mydata GROUP BY data WITH ROLLUP

sum_example|data
----------------
3          |1
12         |2
15         |NULL
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've got a sum working great through my SQL statement aliased as another field. I experimented with WITH ROLLUP, but because I'm grouping by the individual item entries rather than the categories, I don't think I could implement it. I'm mostly concerned with splitting up the result array and showing the category name when it changes and showing a category total at the end of each category.